# How could a hyperparameter grid search be visualised?

Tags: data-visualization, multidimensional-scaling, hyperparameter

Consider a hyperparameter grid search that looks at the training and testing scores of an estimator with respect to multiple parameters like training epochs, number of nodes in layer 1, number of nodes in layer 2, number of nodes in layer 3, number of nodes in layer 4 etc. It's straightforward to create a table ordered by, say, best performance in the testing dataset, but what would be a good way to visualise all of this information in plots?

Comment: This just seems like a special case of the general problem of how to present data that exists in more than three dimensions.

Comment: @user777 Thanks for your comment. Yes, you could well be right. However, I think we could say that there are some variables that are of particular importance (like the score and the epochs) that should be presented particularly clearly. I'm asking not just how to plot multiple variables, I'm asking how to plot multiple variables *given* the field of machine learning and the possible importance of some variables over others.

Comment: Possibly parallel coordinates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates

Comment: The video below is a PLOTCON 2016 talk on Bayesian hyperparameter optimization that explicitly discusses and shows a visualization of grid search. https://youtu.be/L5QSbKt-DfY?t=457

Comment: Simple does it: use a bar chart, or an error bars plot (if you've used CV or alike. Ordinal axis on y (text describing each hyper parameter config), sorted descending by the relevant quantitative x values. You would not want to plot them all, just those that are with in one SE range. Still too many points? then go interactive with tooltips or filtering by hyper parameter value.

Comment: I know this isn't a "solution," per se, but I've had the best luck using just a couple colors for factors and a facet wrap. It seems to allow me to visualize enough hyperparameters at one time in one place.

Comment: If you use Optuna to hyperparameter search your can use a Parallel Co-ordinates Plot [(Documentation)](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/visualization/generated/optuna.visualization.plot_parallel_coordinate.html#optuna.visualization.plot_parallel_coordinate)